# How does plugin system work (wordpress, mybb ...)?

Tags: php, plugins, wordpress

I'm curious how plugins work, I just know that instead of changing the code we use plugins, but how do they do their job without changing the code ?  and what should a coder consider when coding a new project so it can have plugins ?  and thank you very much :D

Comment: Well thank you for telling me about that, because I didn't know about it before, thanks :D

Comment: Can you share your own experience with this subject? It's been a while since you asked the question.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There are multiple variations on how to implement a plugin system. Wordpress uses a quite common scheme often described as "hooks." I don't know the exact implementation but it basically works like this:

```
// plugin.php script registers its own callback function
register_plugin("hook_type", "plugin_function_123");

function plugin_function_123($params) { ... }
```

Where the `hook_type` is often an action name or something. And when the main application runs through a specific point (or e.g. needs some data processsed) it invokes all registered callback functions:

```
$output = call_plugins("hook_type", $param1, $param2);
```

This is often implemented behind the scenes as a simple loop:

```
foreach ($registered_plugins[$action] as $func) {
    $func($param1, $param2, ...);   // or call_user_func_
}
```

Now it depends on the hook/action type what parameters are present, and if any result text is expected. There are also differences in parameter passing (e.g. some callbacks require &$var references). And some plugin systems rely on objects instead (if not as many varying action types exist or more complex structures are to be worked with).

Comment: Though it is marked as answer, could you please briefly describe how "it invokes all registered callback functions"? How the call_plugins() function knows which actions/filters are attached with hook "hook_type"?

Comment: @WebDevron In this rather crude example, `register_*` and `call_plugins()` would share an e.g. global array `$registered_plugins[]` → which in turn associates any functions/callbacks to identifiers (such as "hook_type").

Comment: Thank you for your quick replay. After reading your comment and this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/8336476/2300749) , Now I am clear how it works. Thanks again.