# How to make hooks in php

Tags: php

How can I make hooks in php. I am not sure on how wordpress process their hooks. This is a short example that I wanted to do.

I have a script tag on my register.php file and I wanted it to move on the `**<head>**`

I need an example on how to do this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look at this manual entry : http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.funchand.php

Comment: For a vague description of plugin hooks: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127424/how-does-plugin-system-work-wordpress-mybb/5127470#5127470 - In this case you want the registered callbacks invoked e.g. in the template to output extra content after the `<head>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look here: http://components.symfony-project.org/event-dispatcher/

It's a small and powerful hook library with full documentation

Answer (score 1):

I think you should take a look at one design pattern called **observer pattern**.